# PHP API request

Tags: php, api, http, curl

can anyone help with an API
I having an API that should get parameters in

https://app.wappapi.in/api/send.php?number=9198480xxxxx&type=text&message=test-message&instance_id=609ACF283XXXX&access_token=e10adcxxxxba59axxx56e0xxxxxxxxxx
**in post method**

the question is if I send it like using this god will it get it like needed?

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

$number=$_POST['type'];
$message=$_POST['type'];
$id=$_POST['type'];
$token=$_POST['type'];
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://app.wappapi.in/api/send.php",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "number={$number}type=text&message={$message}&instance_id={$id}&access_token={$token}",
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST"));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you simply asking us if your code will work? Why don't you test it and see? If you have some _specific_ issue (some error or some strange behavior) please add that to the question.

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Please can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, because the query parameters come with the URI

Instead:

```
CURLOPT_URL => "https://app.wappapi.in/api/send.php?number={$number}"
    ."&type=text&message={$message}&instance_id={$id}&access_token={$token}",
CURLOPT_POST => 1
```

Hope it solved your problem.